# Make a variable with array of data from Laravel ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Im struggling to understand Laravels relationship usage. I finally managed to save the relationships between person and festival, using the model and this code:

```
$person = new Person;
$person->firstname = $firstname;
$person->lastname = $lastname;
$person->save();
$person_id = $person->id;
$person->festival()->attach($festival_id);
```

But I am not sure how to make a variable with all the persons of the festival im current working on. I store the value of festival_id in session:

```
$festival_id = Session::get('festival');
```

That is writing fine to my personFestival database.

```
id       festival_id   person_id
0        1             1
1        1             2
```

But i dont have any code in my PersonFestival-model, should I?
How can I retrieve all the persons of the festival with id=1 in a variable that I can use blade's foreach in a view on? Sorry about this mess, this is so confusing for me but i feel that im close to achieving it.

**Tables:**

- persons (id, firstname, lastname)
- festivals (id,name)
- personFestival (id, person_id, festival_id)

Models:

```
class Festival extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $fillable = array(
    'name','year','info','slug', 'image','created_by','updated_by'
);

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'fs_festivals';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function bands() {
    return $this->hasMany('Band');
}

public function persons() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Person','fs_festival_persons','person_id','festival_id');
}
}

class Person extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $fillable = array(
    'email','firstname','lastname','homepage', 'info','tlf','isonline','isbanned','username','password','password_temp','remember_token','code','active','created_by','updated_by'
);

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'fs_persons';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function festival() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('PersonFestival','fs_festival_persons','person_id', 'festival_id');
}
}

class PersonFestival extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $fillable = array(
    'person_id','festival_id'
);

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'fs_festival_persons';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot tables (your fs_festival_persons table) don't usually have a model associated with them, unless you really need some special logic for them.  In this case, it doesn't look like you do, so you can probably just get rid of that model.

To answer your other question, all of the persons associated with a festival can be accessed through the relationship on your festival model:

```
$festival = Festival::find(1);

// Collection of Person objects via lazy loading
$persons = $festival->persons;

// Relationship object:
$relation = $festival->persons();

// Manually getting the Persons through the relationship:
$persons = $festival->persons()->get();

// You can iterate the Collection just like an array:
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    var_export($person->name);
}
```

You can read more on querying relationships here: [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) / [Laravel 5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)